# Giant Table or Smaller Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I have about 40 Million rows per year to add to a table, is it best to have one giant table or to break it up into a table per year?

The data is going to be imported from another data source, so I would have an "AsOf" that would be indexed. The AsOf would be the month for what month the data was pulled from the source system.

My thoughts are that if I have one big table, I can have a query like this:

Select field1, field2, ... from dbo.MyBigTable
Where AsOf = '12/31/2010'
And ...

If i put the data into a table per year I would have to change the query based on what year I am querying and maybe do union's.

Comment: The answer to your question is "partitioning".  You have a classic example where this is useful.  This is a good place to start:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787(v=sql.105).aspx.

Comment: 40 million a year is small depending on your hardware and configuration. As Gordon Linoff mentioned look at partitioning. You could partition the tables over several raid array for example a RAID 10 for fast current access and then a RAID 5(if you must) for historical data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use partitioning . Use one big table and partition data on partition function into years on some hard disks so your disks can work parallel.

Answer (score 0):

> If i put the data into a table per year I would have to change the query based on what year I am querying and maybe do union's

I would say that future T-SQL maintaining can be an issue. Therefore, I'd recommend keeping the 'giant' table with **[other optimizations to consider](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.08.database.aspx)**. Pay attention to the section about **indexes**